# Line-break \jobname

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, jobname

Imagine I have a file called

```
My_very_long_document_name_that_does_not_fit_in_the_left_footer.tex
```

Now I would like to include this long string in the left footer of my document. For this, I use \jobname in the following simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\tiny\jobname}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

As the document name is that big, it overlaps any other element in the remaining footer like page number, etc.
For my real document, it's not possible to place the text a bit above or below the remaining footer, so I really need to break the string in two (or more) lines.

I appreciate very much your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of strategies.

## Use math mode

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand{\breakjobname}{%
  $\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\_\penalty0 }%
   \mathcode`\_=\string"8000 \mathgroup=0
   \jobname$}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\raggedright\tiny\breakjobname.tex}}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

We exploit the fact that `\mathgroup=0` uses the default Roman font.

[image]

## Use `\scantokens`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand{\breakjobname}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\_\penalty0 }%
  \catcode`\_=\active\scantokens\expandafter{\jobname\noexpand}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\parbox[t]{.45\textwidth}{\raggedright\tiny\ttfamily\breakjobname.tex}}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

I've added `\ttfamily` to show that the font changing command is respected.

[image]